# WP Woocommerce Add widget beside Review

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

So we all know that in wordpress woocommerce, there is a product detail tab and review tab in the Single Product page.

I am trying to change the content/comment in the review tab to 70% and have a widget next to the comment. But I don't see to be able to do it. My review form is using WP Advanced comment plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-advance-comment/

Answer (score 0):

It can be changed in the woocommerce/single-product/tabs/tabs.php

```
<div class="wc_reviewbox">
    <div class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper">
        <ul class="tabs wc-tabs" role="tablist">
            <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : ?>
                <li class="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>_tab" id="tab-title-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" role="tab" aria-controls="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
                    <a href="#tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_' . $key . '_tab_title', esc_html( $tab['title'] ), $key ); ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php foreach ( $tabs as $key => $tab ) : 
            echo print_r($tab);
            ?>
            <div class="woocommerce-Tabs-panel woocommerce-Tabs-panel--<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?> panel entry-content wc-tab" id="tab-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-title-<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>">
                <?php call_user_func( $tab['callback'], $key, $tab ); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="wc_adbox">
    [PUT WIDGET CODE HERE]
</div>
```

Do some css manipulation.

```
.wc_reviewbox {
width:72%;float:left;
}

.wc_adbox {
width:25%;float:right;
}
```